# d3 focus on node on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a force layout where clicking on a node will enable focusing on the area around the node. I have looked at a few examples but I am getting an error which says `link.bounds is not defined`. I think the bounds are not defined for force layout and are applicable for this example from where I have taken the focusing functions http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675

What should be the values for `var dx, dy, x` and `y`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    active = d3.select(null);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);    

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", reset);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

var g = svg.append("g");    

d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("click", clicked)
      .call(drag);
});

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function clicked(d){
    if (active.node() === this) return reset();
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

  var bounds = link.bounds(d),
      dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
} 

function reset() {
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(null);

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event);
}    


function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

function zoomed() {
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}    

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-create the zoom effect on a force layout by re-writing the function with the `bbox` of the clicked node:

```
function clicked(d){
  if (active.node() === this) return reset();
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

  var bbox = active.node().getBBox(),
      bounds = [[bbox.x, bbox.y],[bbox.x + bbox.width, bbox.y + bbox.height]]; //<-- the bounds from getBBox

  var dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
}
```

---

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    active = d3.select(null);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);    
    
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
   // .on("click", reset);

var g = svg.append("g");

var link = g.selectAll(".link"),
    node = g.selectAll(".node");

svg
    .call(zoom) // delete this line to disable free zooming
    .call(zoom.event);

d3.json("https://rawgit.com/d3/d3-plugins/master/graph/data/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .style("stroke", "#999");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("click", clicked)
      //.call(drag);
});

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function clicked(d){
  if (active.node() === this) return reset();
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

  var bbox = active.node().getBBox(),
      bounds = [[bbox.x, bbox.y],[bbox.x + bbox.width, bbox.y + bbox.height]];

  var dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
} 

function reset() {
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(null);

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event);
}    


function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

function zoomed() {
  console.log(d3.event)
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}    

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: I tried implementing the same using a different JSON file with source and target in the form of strings rather than indices and it threw a TypeError u.source.x is undefined. I got to know from another question that D3.v3 doesn't support it and one needs to use v4. However, for v4 zoom.translate is undefined. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you so much!