# d3 force directed graph, focus on node double click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have switched my d3 from version 3 to version 4 and as you know there are a lot of breaking changes in between them.
In version 4, I had created following d3 graph:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/C0n0GZvYpppWjx3R

This actually works well, but a challange what I have is, when I do double click of a node, I want this to focus only on the clicked node and all its directly connected node... something like this:
[image]

I am here confused how I can do that...
a. Do I need to remove all other node and redraw the charts?
b. Shall i hide the nodes and links somehow (how?) and only let the focussed (and connected to it) node visible at central.

Can anyone please help here.

Comment: A starting point for you could be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905384/d3-focus-on-node-on-click

Answer (score 2):

Very confused by this question.  You have coded a tremendous graph and the feature you are asking about is 99% coded but its just missing two things:

1. A small typo (`forEach` being used as a keyword, instead of a method, line 228)
2. And is never assigned via an event handler (line 137)

Fixing these [two things](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/mqyuh6kS8ODAXDqJ).

Comment: I am sorry, I just missed to change that...to create plunkr, i copied my workspace . Here forEach was actually _.forEach...
your changes looks good... but I think its just making the nodes/ links invisible, which I already had tried... I was actually looking for something like above image where node is at center of the screen and all connected nodes at almost equal distance. I am little new to this, so not sure how I can actually do that